# Perl regex to replace a comma between characters with a comma and a space

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace the following string

```
camera,photo,image, data
```

with

```
camera, photo, image, data
```

Is this doable with regex in Perl? Note the last word (data) is already separated by a comma and a space so this conversion shouldn't be repeated there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
my $str = 'camera,photo,image, data';
$str =~ s/,(?=\S)/, /g;
say $str;
```

**output:**

```
camera, photo, image, data
```

Answer (score 2):

`,(?! )` replace it with space `', '`

Answer (score 0):

(Spaces do not show very well in the code inserts here, so this answer uses `_` (underscore) where spaces are needed.)

To convert a comma followed by zero or more spaces to a comma followed by one space, replace `,_*` with `,_` (ie replace **comma space asterisk** with **comma space**).

To convert a comma followed by zero or one spaces to a comma followed by one space, replace `,_?` with `,_` (ie replace **comma space question-mark** with **comma space**).